# Using Schema.org's OfferCatalog for separate offers from different sellers

Tags: schema.org, ecommerce

Is it a proper usage when `OfferCatalog` contains offers from different sellers (online marketplace, for instance)?

The intent is to create offer list which contains separate offers from different sellers. Offers presented without any aggregation, one by one. All offered products itself serve the same purpose. It can be a list of screwdrivers, available in certain area, offered by different sellers, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think that the [`OfferCatalog` type](http://schema.org/OfferCatalog) is appropriate in your case.

Its description says:

> An OfferCatalog is an ItemList that contains related Offers and/or further OfferCatalogs that are offeredBy the same provider.

All offers have to be offered by the same provider. One could argue that the online marketplace (and not each seller) is the provider here, but the description of the referenced [`offeredBy` property](http://schema.org/offeredBy) says:

> A pointer to the organization or person making the offer.

The online marketplace isn’t *making* the offer, I assume. Or maybe it is? Then `OfferCatalog` might be appropriate.

If not using `OfferCatalog`, you can still use its parent type [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList), if you prefer to use a list.

Comment: This makes sence. Thank you for confirming my suspiction:)